# Dark Transparent overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, overlay

[image: image with a dark transparent overlay]

Can someone help me, I'm trying to recreate the effect in the image on other photos. It has a dark transparent layer over the image. Can seem to create this same effect.

Answer (score 9):

Simply add a **Color Overlay** layer style to a black and white photo. Set the overlay to `Multiply` and reduce the opacity until you are happy. In this case a blue-grey color is used for the overlay.

[image]